# Cant seem to authenticate to read gmail via Gmail API

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-api-python-client, service-accounts

I have dug through most of stackoverflow posts to find an answer but still unable to solve this problem. This is just a simple matter of authing into the gmail api but I want to do it in a server so I need to follow the server-server (OAuth2.0 2 legged procedure). Anyways 
I have gone through all the oauth docs in google api . 
This one is spot on but it does no good. 
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server.

I have a service account and I do have the creds file.

here is my code snippet.

```
def call_gmail():
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = '<creds_file>'
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
            SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
    print(credentials)
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
    messages = ListMessagesMatchingQuery(service, "me", "<Some email address>")
    message_id = messages[0]['id']
```

I keep getting this error:

`An error occurred: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/history?startHistoryId=2547406&alt=json returned "Bad Request">`

```
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

Would be very grateful if someone can help me solve this. thanks.

Comment: What parameter is "<some email address>" that you are passing to `ListMessagesMatchingQuery`?

Comment: Your project's servcie account, can only access data that belongs to your application, and this means, there is no gmail inbox for the service account; it can make calls to other APIs, as long as it doesn't request user data. If looking to use a service account to access user data (mails), then it needs Domain-Wide-Authorization.

Comment: @Aerials - some email address is a "from" .. it would be "from:<some email address>" ..

Comment: This is a personal account. how can I use domain-wide delegation with a personal account?

Comment: If you want to access user's inbox with Gmail API, you need authorization from the user. Once consent is given, the server will return an access token, and a refresh token for that user to your application. If you don't want to ask the user for consent every time your apps wants to access on their behalf.  Then store the refresh token, and reuse them to obtain a new access token.

Comment: Remember you need to create OAuth Client credentials and configure the OAuth consent screen for you app in the developer console.

Answer (score 0):

The gmail api only works with service accounts if its a Gsuite account and you have set up domain-wide delegation.  Contact your Gsuite admin and make sure that they have setup delegation properly.

[delegating authority](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority)

[image]